# Xcode asks for a password to do some changes

Tags: xcode

Hi I just downloaded Xcode for free after agreeing to the terms and conditions a message pops up saying "Xcode would like to do some changes please type your password" I tried to put apple ID password but it is not working. Please advise

Comment: it's the mac admin password,because xcode wants to access the keychain keystore

Comment: You just need your OS X login and password, not your Apple ID.